# Hi,how can I flip x a collider when the Sprite renderer rotates?

Tags: unity, 2d, platformer

[image]I have been making a 2d platform game in unity.My main character has a box collider but when he rotates, the box dont rotates with him. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are rotating the character by flipping the X on the sprite? So just the sprite gets flipped? If so - then indeed, the collider which is maybe not a symmetrical will not rotate.

To overcome this, the best trick is instead of Flip X use to change scale of the character object on X axis from 1 to -1. Then everything will "flip" :)

Comment: @GeekSince1982 It looks like you could post that as an Answer below.

Comment: Look at that,my main character flip his Sprite,but doesnt his collider.So when he walks to the left,the Sprite goes though the wall